# Unsure how to address type error when creating a function in OCaml

Tags: types, ocaml

The example below explains what the code is supposed to do, and I provided the error message beneath that. This is for a pset for class, so I would very much appreciate explanations to accompany any code solutions! It's of paramount importance to me that I understand it since we have a midterm next week and simply getting a portion of my pset right doesn't help me in the long run.

```
(* the student's name and year *)
type name = string
type year = int
type student = name * year

(*  filter_by_year : returns the names of the students in a given year
 *         Example : let students = [("Joe",2010);("Bob",2010);("Tom",2013)];;
 *                   filter_by_year students 2010 => ["Joe";"Bob"] *)
let filter_by_year (slist:student list) (yr:year) : name list =
    let newlist = List.filter ~f:(fun x -> match x with
        | (a,b) -> b = yr) slist in 
            List.fold_right ~init:[] ~f:(fun x r-> match x with
                | (a,_) -> r :: a)
;;
```

Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from a bad usage of the cons operator `::`. Also, you could have done better!

Note that your `List.fold_right` behaves exactly like a `List.map`. So you can use it and be more concise:

```
let filter_by_year (slist:student list) (yr:year) : name list =
    let newlist = List.filter slist ~f:(fun (a,b) -> b = yr) in
    List.map newlist ~f:fst
```

We can also note that you do two traversals of your list when you could do just one (this time using `fold_right`):

```
let filter_by_year slist yr =
  List.fold_right slist ~init:[]
  ~f:(fun (a,b) result -> if b = yr then a::result else result )
```

Note that if you want to do a real application, you should use some other data structure to avoid going through your whole "database".

Comment: I haven't yet encountered fst; what does that mean?

Comment: `fst` is one of the standard function that gets the first element of a tuple: `fst (x,y) = x`. (Its friend `snd` gets you the second).

Answer (score 1):

First let's try to rewrite your code in a more readable way

```
let filter_by_year (slist:student list) (yr:year) : name list =
    let newlist = List.filter slist ~f:(fun (a,b) -> b = yr) in
    List.fold_right newlist ~init:[] ~f:(fun (a,_) r -> r :: a)
```

You can pattern match directly in the formal parameter, so instead of writing

```
fun x -> match x with
  | (a,_) -> a = d
```

you can write:

```
fun (a,_) -> a = d
```

When the code is clean, the error can be found much easier. When your're folding right (this is CS51, right?) you're using cons operator `::` that expects the list element on the left hand side and the list on the right hand side. Looks like you chose the wrong side.

Comment: Also, the fold_right can be replaced by a simple `List.map fst`.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Thanks for the explanation! However, after compiling the code, I'm getting the error "unbound value d". In case it matters, I'm using gedit as my text editor.

Comment: Hey PatJ, just saw your comment. Could you write that as another solution?

Comment: @dizfunctions I think that by `d`, ivg meant your `yr` variable.

Comment: @dizfunctions, it was general example of pattern matching, you shall not copy paste it, you shall understand it))

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I thought it was a solution and wasn't sure why you would put "d".